# Getting two date time pickers on the same line with bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using eonasdan `datetimepicker` and bootstrap 3. I've got one `datetimepicker` set as calendar and the other as time. I'd like to be able to have them side by side on the same line. But I can't quite figure it out without breaking the `datetimepicker`. Here is my code:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="class">Class:</label> <select multiple
                class="form-control" size="2">
                <option value="1">Class 1</option>
                <option value="2">Class 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- Date Picker -->                
            <div class="input-group date" id="startDate">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" /> <span
                    class="input-group-addon"><span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <!-- Time Picker -->
            <div class="input-group date" id="startTime">
                <input type='text' class="form-control" /> <span
                    class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>


        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[And here is a JSFiddle where the date picker doesn't work but other than that OK](http://jsfiddle.net/6FcBT/). I also can't force the multiple select to only be 2 rows high for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a *css* issue, which can be ***overridden***.  Put both `datepicker` and `Timepicker` within a `div` like

```
<div class="form-group">
<!-- Date Picker -->
    <div class="input-group date " id="startDate">
        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> 
        </span>
    </div>
<!-- Time Picker -->
    <div class="input-group date" id="startTime">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
            </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use CSS:

```
#startDate, #startTime {
    width: 50%;  
    float: left;
}
```

[image]

**Note:** use % value for width to keep it as responsive

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/6FcBT/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to use the bootstrap form classes thinking I wouldn't need any direct CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please check. http://jsfiddle.net/6FcBT/2/

```
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- Date Picker -->              
  <div class="input-group date" id="startDate">
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" />
    </span>

    <!-- Time Picker -->
    <div class="input-group date" id="startTime">   
      <input type='text' class="form-control" /> 
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!--end form-group-->
```

You don't need multiple form group element. If you use one of them you can see the datepicker elements side by side.